# Dotnet Core 1.1 MVC Javascript placed inside @section Scripts{ } is not rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core, sections

I am writing a web application that uses dotnet core 1.1 MVC. I could not figure out why a javascript placed inside @section is not rendered??

I verified my _Layout.cshtml to contain

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Here is how my views are laid out. For brevity, i have consolidated the code.

### (does not work)

Create.cshtml:

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CreateOrEdit", Model);}

@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
```

_CreateOrEdit.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>


@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                language: "de"
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

The challenge i am facing is. the above Scripts section, present in _CreateOrEdit.cshtml is not rendered.

However if i placed this script inside the Scripts section in Create.cshtml as shown below, it is rendered.. what am i doing wrong.?

### (works)

Create.cshtml

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CreateOrEdit", Model);}


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");} 

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
                todayBtn: "linked",
                language: "de"
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

_CreateOrEdit.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the full content of _ValidationScriptsPartial?  Also in the example that doesn't work can you post more of the code that's below the code that you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/myScript.js")` for .js files and `@Styles.Render("~/Content/myStylesheet.css")` for css files when inside a partial view.

However, it's worth mentioning that if your scripts depend on other included scripts such as jquery then you may run into issues with this since you aren't necessarily guaranteed what order the scripts will load in.

It is recommended to include scripts on the parent page (or _layout if it will be needed site wide) as opposed to in a partial view